# Naming pattern for "Path" in docker.json

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and im working on a project that is was written by someone else so Project is multimodular and parent module is called BIH then i have a module account-microservice.  In my docker.json i have such

```
{
  "type": "http",
  "config": {
    "host": "config-server",
    "port": 80,
    "path": "/bih-user-account-microservice/docker.json"
  },
  "scanPeriod": 5000
}
```

I dont understand the path name "bih-user-account-microservice" is this a random name, because if it was a path it should be bih/account-microservice/docker.json. 
My question is can some tell me if Path name can be given some random name ?